# What is the Rust compiler saying here?

Tags: rust, syntax, lifetime-scoping

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `is`
  --> src/bee.rs:76:45
   |
75 | fn compute_instruction_set<'a>(is: &'a mut InstructionSet) {
   |                                    ---------------------- help: add explicit lifetime `'a` to the type of `is`: `&'a mut [OpCode<'a>; 255]`
76 |     let mut isb = InstructionSetBuilder{is: is, pos: 0};
   |                                             ^^ lifetime `'a` required
```

This is the code:

```rust
type InstructionSet<'a> = [OpCode<'a>; 0xff];
...
struct InstructionSetBuilder<'a> {
    is: &'a mut [OpCode<'a>],
    pos: usize,
}
...
fn compute_instruction_set<'a>(is: &'a mut InstructionSet) {
    let mut isb = InstructionSetBuilder{is: is, pos: 0};
...
}
```

Why do I need to set yet another 'a lifetime param?

Where?

I tried several combinations, all broke the syntax...

Comment: By the way, `&'a mut T<'a>` is almost never what you want (the real way to go would be `&'a mut InstructionSet<'b>`, with restriction on `'b: 'a`), since by using `&'a mut T<'a>` we render the object locked behind the exclusuve reference for the whole its existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rust
type InstructionSet<'a> = [OpCode<'a>; 0xff];
```

This type alias is generic over a lifetime `'a`. So you must specify it. Try this instead.

```rust
fn compute_instruction_set<'a>(is: &'a mut InstructionSet<'a>) {
    let mut isb = InstructionSetBuilder{is: is, pos: 0};
...
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, remove the lifetimes from the function signature altogether, since this is a case where it's possible for the compiler to infer them.

Comment: Thank you all! In the end the trick was to use different named lifetimes for the references of things or the containers of references. Then those lifetimes can be omitted in places as the compiler can infer them.